# Redirecting to different pages based on exception type in JSF1.2

Tags: error-handling, custom-error-pages, jsf-1.2

I am trying to show to a special error page for only one of the JSF pages in my application. I tried to throw SpecialException from all the BB methods and entered a error-page mapping with SpecialException entry in web.xml. Still whenever an error occurs, I am redirected to commonerror.xhtml which is associated with javax.faces.FacesException. How to solve this issue?

Comment: The only approach that I figured out is simply to create navigation flows for the exception sequence. The action attribute of the page's components must return a String which should be used for creating the new error page navigation flow.